# Timer task and Thread and inner Class

Tags: java, multithreading, timertask

**Hi everybody . I developed following code. The purpose is : Printing the current time every 500 ms on the screen . This should take place inside a thread . my code doesn't work and I don't know why.**

```
====================================================================

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class MyTimer implements Runnable 
     {
      public class PrintingTask extends TimerTask
      {
           public void run()
           {
                Date CurrentTime = new Date() ; 
                System.out.println(CurrentTime) ; 
            }
       } 
      public void run()
      {
         Timer timer = new  Timer() ; 
         PrintingTask Task1 = new PrintingTask() ; 
         timer.schedule(Task1,500);
       }
      }
  //====================End of the thread : MyTimer========================
    public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       Thread TimerOfScreen = new Thread(new MyTimer());
       TimerOfScreen.start(); 
                      }

  ======================End of the test class=====================
```

The Date is printed only once,not every 500ms. any body can fix this code , "without big change in logic" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the version of `Timer.schedule()` that only runs a task once: [`Timer.schedule(TimerTask, long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29), after the specified delay.

You need to specify one of the versions that actually repeats the task: either [`Timer.schedule(TimerTask, long, long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) or [`Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask, long, long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29). In both of these, the third argument determines how much time will pass between each execution. The difference is that `scheduleAtFixedRate` will try to keep the beginning of each task invocation at a nearly constant period from the start time, while `schedule` will maintain a fairly constant gap between the end of one execution and the beginning of the other.

Comment: Thanks a million buddy.Now it works How I want.